# Conditional onSelectAll in react-bootstrap-table-next?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to implement conditional select and selectAll in `react-bootstrap-table-next`.
Meaning I want to disable the `selectRow` elements when a condition is true.

#### Case:

A user uploads a file - `file has an Upload DateTime` - They shouldn't be allowed to Delete the file unless 15 minutes has passed by.

#### Logic:

`moment() >= moment(row.upload_date).add(15, 'minutes')`

#### UI Implementation:

[image]

#### `selectRow` defenition:

```
const selectRow = {
mode: "checkbox",
selected: selectedFiles.id,
onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
  if ( moment() >= moment(row.upload_date).add(15, 'minutes')) {
    handleOnSelect(row, isSelect);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
},
onSelectAll:(rows, isSelected) => {
  if(isSelected) {
    for(let i = 0 ; i < rows.length ; i++){
      if (moment() >= moment(rows[i].upload_date).add(15, 'minutes')){
        handleOnSelectAll(rows[i], isSelected);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
},
selectionHeaderRenderer: ({ indeterminate, ...rest }) => (
  <Form.Check
    custom
    type="checkbox"
    label={(<></>)}
    ref={ (input) => {
      if (input) input.indeterminate = indeterminate;
    } }
    { ...rest }
  />
),
selectionRenderer: ({ mode ,...rest }) => (
    <Form.Check 
      custom
      type="checkbox"
      label={(<></>)}
      type={ mode } { ...rest } 
    />
)
};
```

#### `handleOnSelect` implementation:

```
const handleOnSelect = (row, isSelect) => {
// Selected file
if (isSelect) {
  if (
    !selectedFiles.length ||
    (selectedFiles.length && selectedFiles[0].id !== row.id)
  ) {
    setSelectedFiles([...selectedFiles, row]);
  }
}
// Deselected file
else {
  setSelectedFiles(selectedFiles.filter((x) => x.id !== row.id));
}
};
```

`handleOnSelect` is working fine.
[image]

#### `handleOnSelectAll` implementation:

```
const handleOnSelectAll = (isSelected, rows) => {
console.log(rows)
let files = rows.map((r) => r);
console.log(files)
// Selected all files
if (isSelected) {
  setSelectedFiles(files);
}
// Deselected all files
else {
  setSelectedFiles([]);
}
};
```

`handleOnSelectAll` isn't working as expected.
[image]

When we click on select all it should not check the file which is recently uploaded.
I have referred to [react-bootstrap-table-next](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/row-select-props.html#selectrowonselectall-function) API documentation but I am failing to implement that.

Please guide me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer to `react-bootstrap-table2` [Styorybook](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Row%20Selection&selectedStory=Advance%20Selection%20Management&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

```
handleOnSelectAll = (isSelect, rows) => {
 if (isSelect) {
  return rows.filter(r => r.id >= 3).map(r => r.id);
 }
}
```

Comment: did you also implement pagination for your use case?